# how to launch a "sudo ..." command automatically at the startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use bluez to connect my ubuntu with my keyboard and my mouse, but each time I have to reboot my computer, I must enter on my other keyboard (an USB one):

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

otherwise, I can not use the bluetooth devices.

I would like to get rid of the other keyboard and the line of code; do you know how this statement could be run automatically at the startup?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Systemd service that runs your command on startup.

Place this unit file inside `/etc/systemd/system` name it "enable-bluetooth.service"

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable Bluetooth

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=hciconfig hci0 up

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then enable it using `systemctl enable enable-bluetooth`

You may now reboot or simply try it out using `systemctl start enable-bluetooth`

Comment: well, thanks but it does not works for me : have a look at my answer please.

Comment: This would work for systemd based Ubuntu versions only. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've got ubuntu 14.04 and the good program with this purpose is update-rc.d (I had to put my bash file in /etc/init.d, then enter "sudo update-rc.d bluetooth.sh defaults").